# Effective Refractive index of a mode less than that of the cladding refractive index?

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, fiber-optics, waveguide, photonics

Can the effective refractive index be less than the cladding if the waveguide width is very small. For example for the case of a ~100 nm waveguide.

Comment: You need to explain the geometry in a little bit more detail.

Comment: For example for a silicon waveguide (450 nm x 220 nm) at 1.55 wavelength, higher order modes will have neff less than fundamental mode, but more than Sio2 cladding(1.45). Can the neff be lesser than 1.45 in that case for higher order modes for very small widths

Answer (score 0):

The neff is bounded by the index of the core and the index of the cladding.  If the fundamental mode is tightly bound then the neff will be much closer for the index of the core.  As the mode grows larger the neff will decrease but won’t ever exactly equal , or be less than , the index of the cladding